# Resources to help with answers to regional difference type questions

Tags: discussion, resources

Here are three recent question examples, including one asked by me:

- [What do you call the space where you park a car? Parking spot, space, bay or what?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/315107/13804)
- [This baby-walking device is called a ([prefix]-)[name] by people from [location]](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/314484/13804)
- [AmEng equivalent for BrEng "decorator"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/314854/13804)

Google will find me lots of dictionary entries and other things to tell me definitions of the words pram, stroller, paperhanger, interior decorator, parking spot, parking bay, and so on.  However, I don't know of any way to find which of these terms are most common in England versus Australia versus the Eastern U.S. versus the Western U.S. versus anywhere else people claim to speak English.

Mostly, I see comments which tell where the user is from, and what that user and his/her friends/ family/ associates call the thing, and whether the user is familiar with the alternative terms.  Definitive, well-resourced answers are hard to come by.

Let's try to assist these askers, answerers, and commenters.  Please provide tips on what resources exist, or what sort of terms to use in searches to obtain reliable information.

Comment: Yes! This is a good idea. I have quite a few questions about regional dialects, and I have not found a good place to research them.

Comment: I believe that the state-of-the-art resource for U.S. regional English is the multivolume _Dictionary of American Regional English_, which is [available (on a subscription basis) online](http://www.daredictionary.com/). I don't have a subscription, nor do I have more than one of the very expensive print volumes in the series. For older British inquiries, all volumes of Joseph Wright's _English Dialect Dictionary_ (1898–1905) are available at Google Books. Harold Wentworth, _American Dialect Dictionary_ (1944) is meticulous about regional sources of words, but no preview is available online.

Comment: The Oxford English Dictionary is probably the definitive resource when it comes to BrE. Their official website is subscription-based (though worth the cost IMO) but there's a pretty decent [website](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/) with reliable definitions.